# Properties.ini file is missing in bitnami stack applications

Tags: wordpress, bitnami

Please help to figure out where the issue could be when installing various bitnami stack applications such as wordpress. It is requesting for properties.ini file of which i don't know where to get it from. Checked online but not much help.
This is the message i'm getting:

"That folder does not seem to contain a valid installation of Bitnami, the properties.ini file is missing. Please specify a valid Bitnami directory or download the Bitnami platform from bitnami.com."

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami developer here,

You are trying to install one of our Bitnami Modules instead of a Bitnami Stack. The module installers are supposed to be installed on top of one of the Bitnami Stacks. For instance, you can install the Bitnami WordPress Module and the Bitnami Joomla Module on top of the Bitnami LAMP Stack. The Bitnami Module installer will check that your are trying to instal
l it on top of the right stack by checking the `properties.ini` file.

If you have already installed our LAMP or WAMP Stacks, you need to specify the LAMP/WAMP installation directory for the check to be successful. If you want to install the complete Bitnami WordPress Stack, you can download it from https://bitnami.com/stack/wordpress/installer

Comment: Thank you for the link provided above. Sorted now.